# How to add an existing df into a class

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class

I have an existing dataframe called df that I need to be imported into this class. Am I allowed to do that and how does it work?

```
def __init__(self,df):

    self.df = df
    
    

the output I get is:

<__main__.solar_model object at 0x7fa1a37ae7c0>
```

Comment: Did you try to print the attribute? `my_instance.df` should give you access to the dataframe

Comment: That output looks like the `repr` of an instance of your class. You can customize the `repr` by implementing a `__repr__` method, which could let you include some of the dataframe's data in the output.

Comment: Yes I used print

Answer (score 0):

You can access the member Dataframe by calling

```py
solar_model.df
```

this will return the Dataframe.
You could use it like `print(solar_model.df)` to print the Dataframe to the console.